# How to add a json credential file of Google drive api alongwith the code when packaging the code written in python?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, setuptools, python-packaging, gspread

I wrote a function in python which uses the json file as the credential file for the Google drive API. The function takes google sheet URL as input and plots graph with the help of gspread library. If I have to make a package of that function how should I include the json file with same path to make the function work as a package? I tried using data_files and MANIFEST.in file as well, but of no use. Upon building the package, I still get the error:

```
No file named credentials.json found
```

when I am testing the package with:

```
pip install -e .
```

I am using setuptools for packaging the code. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`setuptools` has three different ways to specify data files that should be packages together with your project, `Manifest.in`, `data_files`, and `package_data`. For config files that are under your source tree, `package_data` is usually the easiest to use.

---

Given a very small sample project that looks like this:

```
.
├───setup.py
└───tmp
    ├───__init__.py 
    └───keys.json
```

You'd need a `setup.py` file with at least this configuration to package all code and `.json` files under `tmp` :

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="tmp",
    version="0.1.0",
    packages=["tmp"],
    package_data={"tmp": ["*.json"]},
)
```

The `keys.json` file only contains `{"key": "foo"}`.

The safest way to parse packaged config files from within your package is to use [`importlib.resources`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources) to access it, in particular its `path` function (if you are stuck on python 3.7 or older, [`importlib_resources`](https://pypi.org/project/importlib-resources/) is an equivalent pip-installable backport):

**`tmp/__init__.py`**

```py
from importlib import resources
import json

def print_keys():
    with resources.path("tmp", "keys.json") as foo_path:
        print(json.load(foo_path.open()))
```

Once I install this package with `pip install -e .`, I can run:

```py
>>> import tmp
>>> tmp.print_keys()
{'key': 'foo'}
```

---

If you plan to work with python packaging for a while, consider using a more modern build-backend than setuptools, such as [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) or [flit](https://flit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). They make the experience *a lot* more bearable.

Comment: I tried doing it, but it is not working in my case at least. It still shows No .json file found.

Comment: are you sure the path to the json file is correct? If it doesn't even work during a local editable install, then the error can't happen during packaging - so it should be during file access